# enumerate causes incompatible type mypy error

Tags: python, mypy, typing, enumerate

The following code:

```
from typing import Union


def process(actions: Union[list[str], list[int]]) -> None:
    for pos, action in enumerate(actions):
        act(action)


def act(action: Union[str, int]) -> None:
    print(action)
```

generates a mypy error:  `Argument 1 to "act" has incompatible type "object"; expected "Union[str, int]"`

However when removing the enumerate function the typing is fine:

```
from typing import Union


def process(actions: Union[list[str], list[int]]) -> None:
    for action in actions:
        act(action)


def act(action: Union[str, int]) -> None:
    print(action)
```

Does anyone know what the enumerate function is doing to effect the types?
This is python 3.9 and mypy 0.921

Comment: Statically, you can't write a more specific return type for `enumerate.__next__` than `Tuple[int, Any]`, because the runtime return type is specified solely by the runtime argument to `enumerate`. Using a generic wouldn't help, because the iterable being enumerated doesn't need to have a homogenous type. I think `mypy` would need to be modified to take a static type hint for the argument into account in order to infer that `action` has type `Union[str, int]` rather than `Any`.

Comment: FWIW, if you change `Union[list[str], list[int]]` to `list[Union[str, int]]` or (arguably better yet) `Iterable[Union[str, int]]`, then mypy can work out that the type of `action` is `Union[str, int]`.

Comment: @jjramsey That changes the type, though.  It would make `[1, 'x', 3]` valid where before it was not. (But it does give me an idea...)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`enumerate.__next__` needs more context than is available to have a return type more specific than `Tuple[int, Any]`, so I believe `mypy` itself would need to be modified to make the inference that `enumerate(actions)` produces `Tuple[int,Union[str,int]]` values.

Until that happens, you can explicitly cast the value of `action` before passing it to `act`.

```
from typing import Union, cast

StrOrInt = Union[str, int]

def process(actions: Union[list[str], list[int]]) -> None:
    for pos, action in enumerate(actions):
        act(cast(StrOrInt, action))


def act(action: Union[str, int]) -> None:
    print(action)
```

You can also make `process` generic (which now that I've thought of it, is probably a better idea, as it avoids the overhead of calling `cast` at runtime).

```
from typing import Union, cast, Iterable, TypeVar

T = TypeVar("T", str, int)

def process(actions: Iterable[T]) -> None:
    for pos, action in enumerate(actions):
        act(action)


def act(action: T) -> None:
    print(action)
```

Here, `T` is not a union of types, but a single concrete type whose identity is fixed by the call to `process`. `Iterable[T]` is either `Iterable[str]` or `Iterable[int]`, depending on which type you pass to `process`. That fixes `T` for the rest of the call to `process`, which every call to `act` must take the same type of argument.

An `Iterable[str]` or an `Iterable[int]` is a valid argument, binding `T` to `int` or `str` in the process. Now `enumerate.__next__` apparently *can* have a specific return type `Tuple[int, T]`.

Comment: Thanks for the response have raised with mypy here https://github.com/python/mypy/issues/11934

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how it's affecting the types. I do know that using len() can work the same way. It is slower but if it solves the problem it might be worth it. Sorry that it's not much help

Comment: Thanks, yeah there are workarounds but i think this should work so ill raise on GitHub

Comment: Sounds good. Again, I'm really sorry I couldn't do more

Answer (score 0):

Seems like mypy isn't able to infer the type and generalizes to object. Might be worth opening an issue at their side. As a workaround you could annotate 'action'. This would remove the error. Does it work if you import the (legacy) `List` from `typing`?

Comment: Thanks, yeah okay i will do. Tried with legacy List and same error

Comment: Interesting. Nice catch

Comment: Raised here https://github.com/python/mypy/issues/11934